# Como mudar o aspecto do site de acordo com o dispositivo usado, sem precisar de script no cliente ou no servidor?

Tags: css, html

Alguém aqui sabe criar um site responsivo do zero?

Sem usar um framework como o Bootstrap?

Preciso disso, pois recebo *layouts* em PSD todo personalizado e seria mais fácil criar do zero, já que em um período não muito distante do que todos os sites terão que ser compatíveis com celulares.

Comment: *[...] seria mais fácil [...]*. Em geral é mais fácil não reinventar coisas prontas, não tentar atacar problemas já resolvidos. Um jeito bastante fácil é usar Bootstrap em LESS -- vc pode criar seu próprio grid em pouquíssimas linhas e reaproveitar tudo o que já está pronto.

Comment: O melhor que já vi foi o http://ink.sapo.pt/‎ Int Interface Kit, onde você pode facilmente configurar as formas do seu site de acordo com o tamanho médio das telas de dispositivos, usando apenas CSS e JS open source.

Answer (score 3):

Estude Media Queries, com ele você define os tamanhos em que vai haver modificação no layout, por exemplo:

Quando chegar no tamanho mínimo de largura de 767px troque a cor do background por outra.

Aqui tem alguns exemplos:

```
/* Smartphones (retrato e paisagem) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (paisagem) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (retrato) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (retrato e paisagem) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (paisagem) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (retrato) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops e laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Resoluções grandes ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

fonte: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Estude Media Querie! A princípio pode ficar um pouco confuso pelo fato de sempre desenvolver para um único tamanho de layout, por exemplo aquele velho 960px de largura, etc. Mas, quer uma dica legal? Busque aí alguns sites responsivos e estude o CSS deles, sempre foi muito útil pra mim! Esse [artigo](http://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/) do tableless.com também e bacana.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que não da pra explicar exatamente o que você procura com uma simples resposta, mas eu recomendo dar uma lida [neste artigo](http://www.devmedia.com.br/responsive-design-dicas-para-tornar-seu-site-acessivel-em-qualquer-resolucao/28316), que vai lhe esclarecer algumas técnicas para seu layout ser responsivo.

A matéria toca em assuntos que você vai precisar como:

- Media Query
- Resoluções frequentes
- Min Max width

Comment: Olá. Faço o mesmo comentário que fiz para outra resposta nesta pergunta: seria bacana você complementar a sua resposta com alguns pontos principais ou exemplos do artigo que citou. Vai que o link fica indisponível, alguém que chega aqui não consegue obter nada da ajuda que tanto procura... :)

Answer (score 0):

Um começo seria:

1. Usar propriedades `max-height`, 'max-width', `overflow: hidden`, etc.
2. Usar media query no mesmo css usado para dispositivos maiores:

   ```
   @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
       img.bg {
           left: 50%;
           margin-left: -512px;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Usar arquivos css próprios para dispositivos com menor resolução:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="smartphones.css" media="screen and (max-width:480px)">
   ```

Entre outros.

Answer (score 0):

Existe a possibilidade de se criar um site responsivo sem utilização de um framework, porém usá-los irá facilitar a sua vida e consequentemente ganhar tempo pelo fato de que ter várias coisas "prontas". Não recomendo utilizar se você for iniciante, acredito que elimina uma fase do aprendizado.

Eu desenvolvi projetos com diversos frameworks dentre eles, BootStrap, Foundation, Semantic Ui e atualmente não utilizo porque nem sempre o código é bem organizado, não uso tantas classes e a semântica utilizada é horrível.

Uma dica bacana é ler um pouco de Mobile First, Media Queries, Medidas Relativas. Não utilize gambiarras no projeto, a organização na etapa inicial vai lhe ajudar bastante no decorrer do mesmo.